# Scroll view is scrolling when content is fully visible

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem: my scroll view scrollable, when content is fully visible. What should i do, to enable scrolling, when some part of content is hidden?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution. I faced the same issue few months back.

```
public override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    ScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    ScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
}
```

Enjoy!